# How to have dynamic base URL with Quarkus MicroProfile Rest Client?

Tags: quarkus, microprofile, restclientbuilder

[Quarkus using Rest Client](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client), explains how to use the MicroProfile REST Client. For Base URL application.properties can be used.

```
org.acme.restclient.CountriesService/mp-rest/url=https://restcountries.eu/rest #
```

With above approach, cant have dynamic base URL.

Able to achieve it by using RestClientBuilder as explained in [MicroProfile Rest Client](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-1.2.1/microprofile-rest-client-1.2.1.html#release_notes_10). Downside of this approach is not having auto-negotiation capability.

```
SimpleGetApi simpleGetApi = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().baseUri(getApplicationUri()).build(SimpleGetApi.class);
```

Is there other or better way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Why is auto-negotiation important? Quarkus documentation does not encourage using it: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. Can you provide more information about the use-case of dynamic base URL and why auto-negotiation is needed? You can simply add `@Consumes` or `@Produces` and then auto-negotiation should not be needed and therefore `RestClientBuilder` would work fine

Comment: Thanks @PanuHaaramo, RestClientBuilder enforces to have Return Type asjavax.ws.rs.core.Response, whereas with quarkus Rest client it can return anything (e.g. MyObject)

Comment: Thanks @AndyGuibert, use case for dynamic URL could be sandbox in URL. Like http://dev.hostname and http://test.hostname, where sandbox could be dynamically created (like test1) - Not sure if that is best strategy.  For auto-negotiation refer my comment above.

Comment: How does it enforce that return type? I think you can return anything from your methods in SimpleGetApi.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that dynamic configuration. Does the URL need to change without restarting the application? If not, you can override the base URL using MP Config. See here: https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-1.2.1/microprofile-rest-client-1.2.1.html#mpconfig

Comment: Thanks again @AndyGuibert, As sandbox is being created run-time, URL does need to change without restarting application.

Comment: Thanks @PanuHaaramo, If MyObject is used in SimpleGetApi return type. It throws exception "Unable to find MessageBodyReader of content-type".

Comment: If you need to change the URL at runtime see the answer bellow. If you just want to change that URL based on Environment, for example different URL on dev and prod, then you can simply override that config property - like any other config, for example via ENV vars, see https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference

Answer (score 7):

While it is true, that the MP Rest CLient does not allow you to set the BaseUri dynamically when you use declarative/Injected clients, there are some (albeit hacky) ways how to achieve that.

One is to use standard `ClientRequestFilter` which can modify the URL:

```java
@Provider
@Slf4j
public class Filter implements ClientRequestFilter {

  @Inject RequestScopeHelper helper;

  @Override
  public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    if (helper.getUrl() != null) {
      URI newUri = URI.create(requestContext.getUri().toString().replace("https://originalhost.com", helper.getUrl()));
      requestContext.setUri(newUri);
    }
  }
}
```

Where `RequestScopeHelper` is some help class (e.g. request scoped bean) through which you can pass the dynamic url, for example:

```java
@Inject
RequestScopeHelper helper;

@Inject
@RestClient
TestIface myApiClient;
 
public void callSomeAPIWithDynamicBaseUri(String dynamic) {
  helper.setUrl(dynamic);
  myApiClient.someMethod();
}
```

Second is to use MP rest client SPI, namely the [RestClientListener](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-1.4-RC2/apidocs/org/eclipse/microprofile/rest/client/spi/RestClientListener.html) which allows you to modify the rest clients after they are built.

For this to work, you have to set the scope of your rest client to `RequestScoped` so that new instance is created for each request(if you use singleton for example, then the client is only created once and your listener will only be called once). This you can do via quarkus properties:

```
quarkus.rest-client."com.example.MyRestIface".scope=javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

```java
public class MyListener implements RestClientListener {

  @Override
  public void onNewClient(Class<?> serviceInterface, RestClientBuilder builder) {
    String newUri = //obtain dynamic URI from somewhere e.g. again request scope bean lookup, or maybe dynamic config source (create new in-memory ConfigSource, before you invoke your rest client set the corresponding rest client url property to your dynamic value, then inside this listener use ConfigProvider.getConfig().getProperty...)
    builder.baseUri(URI.create(newUri));
  }
}
```

Don't forget to register this listener as service provider(`META-INF/services/org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.spi.RestClientListener`)

Another option is to use custom CDI producer that would produce the Rest client instances for you; then you could control all client config yourself. You can use the `RestClientBase` [from Quarkus rest client](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/125879f3023c9c49c575612ccaf145863f90cc21/extensions/resteasy-classic/rest-client/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/restclient/runtime/RestClientBase.java#L56) which is exactly what Quarkus uses under the hood during deployment phase to construct client instances. You will however have to duplicate all the logic related to registration of handlers, interceptors etc.

Do keep in mind, that any of these solutions will make the debugging and problem analysis more challenging - because you will now have multiple places, where the URI is controlled(MP config/quarkus properties, env vars, your custom impl...), so you need to be careful with your approach and maybe add some explicit log messages when you override the URI manually.

Answer (score 2):

MicroProfile REST Client in Quarkus does allow you to use dynamic base URL with that simple "hack" :

Just put an empty `String` in `@Path` annotations for you API interface like that :

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("")
public interface SimpleGetApi {
    @Path("")
    @GET
    String callWithDynmamicUrl(); //it can be String or any return type you want
}
```

After that you are ready to call your dynamic base URL :

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientBuilder;
import java.net.URI;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URI anyDynamicUrl = URI.create("http://restcountries.eu/rest/some/dynamic/path");
        SimpleGetApi simpleGetApi = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().baseUri(anyDynamicUrl)
                .build(SimpleGetApi.class);
        simpleGetApi.callWithDynmamicUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me but don't forget to make your interface extend Closeable.

Comment: This works ok yet now CDI will not be aware of the instance preventing things like decorators working with it